# What is an Ask Ubuntu Meta User?

Tags: discussion, users

I'm new to Ask Ubuntu, and I found an "Ask Ubuntu meta" link on my User page.
I don't know what it is, so can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: This belongs on Meta _O-

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-meta

Answer (score 3):

The short answer:

Meta-discussion site (Ask Ubuntu Meta), is where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags should be used, suggest a feature, point out a bug, or generally discuss how this site works.<sup>[Ubuntu Help](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)</sup>